# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context downloadTask Swift

Tags: swift

Here is my function:

```
 func textToSpeech(transcript: String) async throws {
        
        let key = MICROSOFT_SUB_KEY
        let region = "eastus"
           
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken") else { fatalError("Missing URL") }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue((key as! String), forHTTPHeaderField: "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key")
        request.setValue("application/ssml+xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("audio-16khz-128kbitrate-mono-mp3", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Microsoft-OutputFormat")
        request.setValue("curl", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        let bodyString = "<speak version='\''1.0'\'' xml:lang='\''en-US'\''><voice xml:lang='\''en-US'\'' xml:gender='\''Female'\'' name='\''en-US-JennyNeural'\''>my voice is my passport verify me this is such a great tool</voice></speak>"
        request.httpBody = Data(bodyString.utf8)

        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: request)
        
        guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { print("ERROR RESPONSE ------>", response)
            return }
    }
```

When I print the `data` out from my `textToSpeech` function, it shows the bytes output of my audio file:

`777 bytes`

However, when I try to download the audio file with `downloadTask`, I get the following error:

`Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

How can I download the audio file, save it to a URL, and then play it?

Comment: `URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: request)` this is not a function that uses async/await, you want to use [data(for:delegate:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767352-data) or similar. Please check the documentation for URLSession

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Can you show a code example? I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the delegate part of the ```data``` function

Comment: There are so many examples available online on how to use the async/await version of URLSession so you shouldn’t have a problem finding one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this line:

```swift
let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: request)
```

If you want a `Data` (as suggested by name of `data`), it would be [`data(for:delegate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767352-data):

```swift
let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
```

Or, if downloading to a file (as suggested by use of `downloadTask`), it would be [`download(for:delegate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767354-download):

```swift
let (downloadURL, response) = try await URLSession.shared.download(for: request)
```